# Prevent a user to access a page in some situations or directly

Tags: django, redirect, django-views

I have an Account Model which have a field is_active(Boolean) by default false,
and a Company Model with foreign key to account:

```
class Account(Meta):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

In the `get` method of CBV I check if user is active an if is not I redirect him to a different url page.

```
        if not account.is_active:
            return redirect('accounts:inactive')
        return account
```

Url:

```
path('inactive/', AccountInactiveView.as_view(), name='inactive'),
```

view for redirect:

```
class AccountInactiveView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'accounts/account_inactive.html'
```

I don't want the redirect page/url to be access by anyone **directly** especially if Account is active field is True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get()` method should return an `HttpResponse`. It doesn't make sense to return `account` there. Perhaps you want to call `super()`:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    account = self.request.user.account
    if not account:
        raise Http404
    if not account.is_active:
        return redirect('accounts:inactive')
    return super(MyView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

It might be better to override `dispatch`, so that the check is carried out for `get` and `post` requests.

Comment: ok, thanks, what about preventing the user to access directly the 'inactive' page

Comment: You could return `render('accounts/account_inactive.html')` instead of a redirect, and then there won't be a url or view to access the page. Or add a check to `AccountInactiveView` and don't allow accounts with `active=True`.

Comment: thanks, adding a check is checking twice, once before the redirect and again after redirect in some cases; If there is no why to send an argument to tell that it shouldn't I will try with render

Comment: If you did "send an argument" (e.g. in the querystring `?nocheck=1` or in the session), then you would have to check the argument in the view, and worry about whether the user could spoof it. Checking account again is much simpler, and will be so quick that you won't notice in practice.